# Running docker image hangs and then times out in the prod server

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

I have a docker image that I can run properly in my local VM. Everything runs fine.

I save the image and load it in the prod server.

I can see the image by using `docker images`

next I try to run it with `docker run -p 9191:9191 myservice`

It hangs and eventually times out.

The log shows the following:

`time="2018-08-15T16:14:35.058232400-07:00" level=debug msg="HCSShim::CreateContainer succeeded id=b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e4152 handle=
39044064" 
time="2018-08-15T16:14:35.058232400-07:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: Create() id=b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e4152, Calling start()" 
time="2018-08-15T16:14:35.058232400-07:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: starting container  b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e4152" 
time="2018-08-15T16:14:35.058232400-07:00" level=debug msg="HCSShim::Container::Start id=b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e4152" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.393050900-07:00" level=debug msg="Result: {\"Error\":-2147023436,\"ErrorMessage\":\"This operation returned because the timeout period expired.\
"}" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.394050800-07:00" level=error msg="libcontainerd: failed to start container: container b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db7
9e4152 encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: This operation returned because the timeout period expired. (0x5b4)" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.394050800-07:00" level=debug msg="HCSShim::Container::Terminate id=b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e4152" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.394050800-07:00" level=debug msg="libcontainerd: cleaned up after failed Start by calling Terminate" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.394050800-07:00" level=error msg="Create container failed with error: container b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e4152
 encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: This operation returned because the timeout period expired. (0x5b4)" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.424053800-07:00" level=debug msg="attach: stdout: end" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.425055000-07:00" level=debug msg="attach: stderr: end" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.427054100-07:00" level=debug msg="Revoking external connectivity on endpoint boring_babbage (b20f403df0ed25ede9152f77eb0f8e049677f1279b68862a25b
b9e2ab94babfb)" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.459087300-07:00" level=debug msg="[DELETE]=>[/endpoints/31e66619-5b57-47f2-9256-bbba54510e3b] Request : " 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.548068700-07:00" level=debug msg="Releasing addresses for endpoint boring_babbage's interface on network nat" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.548068700-07:00" level=debug msg="ReleaseAddress(172.25.224.0/20, 172.25.229.142)" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.561064000-07:00" level=debug msg="WindowsGraphDriver Put() id b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e4152" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.561064000-07:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::UnprepareLayer flavour 1 layerId b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e4152" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.566074800-07:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::UnprepareLayer succeeded flavour 1 layerId=b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db7
9e4152" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.566074800-07:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::DeactivateLayer Flavour 1 ID b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e4152" 
time="2018-08-15T16:18:25.668075600-07:00" level=debug msg="hcsshim::DeactivateLayer succeeded flavour=1 id=b928213e42b2103cd33b676ed08a15529be10fffcfd7e709af86df5db79e41
52"`

I can see when it is trying to create the container and then it fails.

But why?

---

added more information

I finally found out how to check the server status for running container and I am getting this error message:

[image: NAT error]

So it means the server doesn't have a network gateway? 
How can I fix this problem? 
Still keep looking

---

More information
I did delete all NAT and create a new one, so the online check passed now.

[image]

However, I still encounter other errors and can't run the image. 
Something in the virtual network is wrong, I just can't find the right information to fix it.... :(

Comment: You can check if there is enough resource for the container.